# Form submission using Ajax/Jquery

Tags: php, performance, jquery

When I first started web development with php, when using POST I would have the page with the form that contained the information and then another php page which the “action” attribute pointed to and hence where the all the processing i.e. database work was done. After making a website with many forms I found that I was building up lots of pages and it was getting quite messy.

Then I started to look for a way to avoid this. I then found that I could post a page to itself and hence halving the amount of pages that I needed to use to submit a form. I did this using the isset() function in php. The problem with this is that the whole page needed to be refreshed.

Even more towards the future I discovered jquery and its use of ajax to submit forms etc. This led me back to me original problem of having too many pages and getting confused with what did what. So now I am wondering (although I’m not quite sure I can make sense of it) if there is a way to combine the two? Can jquery use ajax to process a form which points to itself?

The other options that I was thinking of would be to have one page that I send all forms and actions to, which has all my processing in and determine which section to use based on a switch. I’m not sure of the effects that this would have on performance though.

- What views do you have on each of the methods?
- What are the pros/cons?
- Are any of the methods I mentioned frowned upon/bad practice?

This question has been baffling me for a while now, and so I thought it best to get the thoughts of the experts.

Thanks in advance.

Adam Holmes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the answer is quite simple. Jquery uses AJAX to request pages the same way as you would with a regular form. Thus you can use jquery to post information from the form on the page itself, and then as you would normally with isset() do whatever you want.
The obvious advantage is that you don't need to refresh the page, and everything seems more seamless. However sometimes you will need to refresh anyway, for instance during logging in. The disadvantage is that users with javascript off will not be able to use that form, however from my experience this now mostly applies on mobile devices, and in limited manner even then.
I would say that using jquery/ajax to submit your forms is the way to go, just be sure to provide javascript-less alternative if it is something essential and if you receive a lot of traffic from mobile devices.

Somebody else will probably provide more elaborate answer, so take this just as a little summary.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery can process it, and send anywhere you want :-)

Don't you thinked about using some kind of classes and autoload ( PHP 5 ) ? - it makes choosing in your second option much simpler ( somepage.php?class=Foo&.... )

Comment: Could you explain that a little further?

Comment: PHP 5 supports this - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php . And this - http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php . It simplies choosing right target from main script. Another thing - jQuery can send your form data as normal $_POST - so no changes in your server-side